# Integration by parts is not working.

Tags: calculus

I an trying to solve $$\int_{-R}^{R}\tan^{-1}(\sin^2(x))dx$$ with Integration by Parts, by integrating 1 and differentiating our integrand, yielding $$2R\tan^{-1}(\sin^2(x))-2\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{x\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\sin^4(x)+1}$$ and when I plug these into Desmos they yield different results. This probably has something to do with my assumption of the principal value of $\tan^{-1}(\sin^2(x))$, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I don't think it's integral exists in elementary functions.

Comment: $\tiny I=x\tan^{-1}(\sin^2(x))-\frac{1}{4}i(i(\text{Li}_2(((1-2i)+2\sqrt{-1-i})e^{2ix})+\text{Li}_2(((1-2i)-2\sqrt{-1-i})e^{2ix}))-i(\text{Li}_2(((1+2i)+2\sqrt{-1+i})e^{2ix})+\text{Li}_2(((1+2i)-2\sqrt{-1+i})e^{2ix}))-2\log(1+(-1+2i+2\sqrt{-1-i})e^{2ix})(x-\sin^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{-1}))-2\log(1+((-1+2i)-2\sqrt{-1-i})e^{2ix})(x+\sin^{-1}(\sqrt[4]{-1}))+2\log(1+(-1-2i+2\sqrt{-1+i})e^{2ix})(x+\sin^{-1}((-1)^{3/4}))+2\log(1-((1+2i)+2\sqrt{i-1})e^{2ix})(x-\sin^{-1}((-1)^{3/4}))-4i\sin^{-1}((-1)^{3/4})\tan^{-1}(\frac{2\tan(x)}{(i-1)^{3/2}})-4\sin^{-1}(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{-1-i}\tan(x)))$

Comment: where $I=\int\arctan\sin^2xdx$. Combining with that the integrand is even, the original integral is not elementary.

Comment: In your "uv" part, you still have an $x$, inside the $\sin.$

Comment: Wait, are you not allowed to do integration by parts on non elementary functions?

Comment: Because i'll be evaluating the new integral using contour integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error was with Desmos. My plan was to divide both sides by $\frac{1}{2R}$ to make this an average value and take $R\to\infty$ which allows me to use Jordan's lemma of the integral. The issue is, the integral is kind of messy so for large values of $R$ the value will not be equal, but in reality the integration by parts is correct and there is no error in the integration.